# Maximize Resize Images in Powerpoint using Applescript

Tags: image, resize, applescript, powerpoint

I am using MS Powerpoint 2008 on my macbook. I have used the provided Automator action to add a bunch of images (100 or so) into a new PPTX file. The images are centered, but they are not completely maximized. There is about 0.5-1 inch of space around the edges that could be used. I prefer the images to be maximized either vertically or horizontally, or whichever is appropriate for the image.

Any idea how to add code that would determine if the image (shape) would better be maximized to the slide height (7.5 in x 72 px/in) or width (10 in or 720 px)?

Here is my code so far:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    set thePres to active presentation
    set slideCount to count slides of thePres
        repeat with a from 1 to slideCount
        set theShape to first shape of slide a of thePres
        set height of theShape to (7.5 * 70)
        set leftPos to (slide width of page setup of thePres) - (width of theShape)
        set left position of theShape to (leftPos / 2)
        set top of theShape to 0
    end repeat
end tell
```

Here is my updated code after implementing suggestion. I had to add a line to check that the height did not exceed the slide height after resizing in cases where the image was wider than tall, but was not the same ratio as 7.5 x 10 in slide:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    set thePres to active presentation
    set slideCount to count slides of thePres
    repeat with a from 1 to slideCount
        set theShape to first shape of slide a of thePres
        if height of theShape is greater than width of theShape then
            set height of theShape to (7.5 * 72)
        else
            set width of theShape to (10 * 72)
        end if
        if height of theShape is greater than 540 then
            set height of theShape to 540
        end if
        set leftPos to (slide width of page setup of thePres) - (width of theShape)
        set left position of theShape to (leftPos / 2)
        set top of theShape to 0
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why "set height of theShape to (7.5 * 70)" ?

The default slide height would be 7.5 * 72 (7.5 inches * 72 points per inch)

Assuming the images are already added to the slides, you'd want to look at the width of the image divided by the height.  If the result is 1 or less, the image is square or taller than wide, so you'd want to center it vertically.  If it's >1 then center it horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The 70 was a typo. I should be using 72 as you suggest.